# What is the difference between using .apply or passing a column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to apply a simple function to a column in a Pandas Dataframe. I have done it in two different ways:

- 1.`df['column1']=myFunction(df['column1'])`
- 2.`df['column1']=df['column1'].apply(lambda x:myFunction[x])`

My dataset is not that big to be able to tell the difference but I am guessing it will have to do with speed.

Can anyone explain what the difference is and which is one preferred?

Answer (score 2):

- 1.`df['column1']=myFunction(df['column1'])`

Here you are defining a function to be applied on a `pd.Series`. You're letting pandas handle how that's going to happen.

- 2.`df['column1']=df['column1'].apply(lambda x:myFunction[x])`

Here you are applying a function on each element.

In general, option 1 will be faster than option 2. It heavily depends on what's your actual `myFunction`, if this one is vectorized or element by element.

---

Case example:

Let's create a dataframe with 2 columns and 100,000 rows (big enough to appreciate the difference in speed), and square the elements of `column1`:

```
In [1]: 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000,2),
                  columns=['column1','column2'])

def myFunction(s):
    return s**2

In [2]: %%timeit
    ...: myFunction(df.column1)
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 ms per loop

In [3]: %%timeit
    ...: df.column1.apply(lambda x: x**2)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 55.4 ms per loop
```

So here you see it's more than 30 times faster to do the operation on `pd.Series` rather than element by element. That's because the `myFunction` is vectorized.

---

Now, let's take an example where your `myFunction` is not vectorized but element by element:

```
In [4]: def myFunction(s):
...:     return s.apply(lambda x: x**2)
...: 

In [4]: %%timeit
    ...: myFunction(df.column1)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 53.9 ms per loop
```

Basically it's the same as doing a direct `apply`